# Shared authorized_keys, known_hosts and SSH key amongst a group of users and servers

Tags: ssh

We have 5 production servers, each with 2 users that we use for some applications.

i.e. `server01` though to `server05` and `user1` and `user2`.

We want it to be possible to SSH from any user on any server to any user on any other server.

e.g. `user1` on `server01` to `user2` on `server05` and so forth.

Is it possible to create a SSH key and share this amongst all users on all servers?

Is there some global directory for storing the `authorized_keys`, `known_hosts` and SSH key on each server, that is shared amongst both users on the server?

Looking for the simplest method to achieve this.

Comment: Setup puppet, manage your users and authorized_keys files via puppet.  Push the keys to all the systems/users.  Use puppet to collect your and redistribute your known_hosts to all your systems.

Comment: Doesn't have to be puppet, any config management tool would do.

Answer (score 0):

A config management tool like puppet would help with something like this. However if you don't want to learn any new tools it wouldn't take too much time to do it manually if you only have five servers and 2 users.

If you don't care about auditing or security it is possible to share the same SSH key between all end users and all server user accounts. You could use a simple shell script to automate this.

```
for server in server1.com server2.com server3.com; do
  ssh $server sh << "END"
  for user in user1 user2; do
    echo 'ssh public key goes here' | tee ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
    echo 'ssh private key goes here' >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  done
END
done
```

However "correct", secure, and more autitable way to do this would be to have separate user accounts for each user then use sudo to grant access to other accounts for specific commands based on what the user end user needs to do.